# Создают ли на php отдельный api, и зачем?

Tags: php, api

Я только-только изучаю php и тут возник ступор, который не дает мне продвигаться дальше, а гугл не очень помогает.

Создают ли на php отдельный api, и если да, то зачем? Ведь бэк на php пишется прямо в файле с версткой и все взаимодействия происходят сразу в нем, там даже не нужен js для отправки запросов к серверу. Скорее всего, я где-то что-то не так понимаю, и что-то мне подсказывает, что ошибка в понимании клиент-сервер.

И дело еще в том, что фронт и бэк пишут одновременно разные разработчики, но как бэк пишет функциональность без фронта, если делать все в одном файле с версткой...

Comment: `но как бэк пишет функциональность без фронта, если делать все в одном файле с версткой...` что ВЦ? вам еще стоит подучить мат часть...

Comment: `Создают ли на php отдельный api, и зачем?` создают) потому что разработчикам удобно

Comment: в одном файле с версткой пишут не код, а говнокод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Создают ли на php отдельный api, и если да, то зачем?

Да, потому что некоторые виды API удобно создавать на PHP. Для примера можно взять тот же Callback API у ВКонтакте, чтобы что-то сделать вам достаточно открыть в браузере (либо программно отправить GET запрос) ссылку формата "https://api.vk.com/method/<название.метода>?<параметры>" и получить ответ в виде JSON.

> Ведь бэк на php пишется прямо в файле с версткой и все взаимодействия происходят сразу в нем, там даже не нужен js для отправки запросов к серверу.

Если я вас правильно понял, вы не совсем правильно понимаете как работает PHP. Весь код выполняется на сервере, а то что вы выводите (например с помощью echo) отправляется пользователю как HTML страница и поэтому, если вы хотите например получить пользовательский ввод, вам может понадобиться "вывести" JS код в специальном теге script (на самом деле не обязательно (как вариант, можно использовать обычный тег form), но расписывать всё будет проблематично :).

> И дело еще в том, что фронт и бэк пишут одновременно разные разработчики, но как бэк пишет функциональность без фронта, если делать все в одном файле с версткой...

Не обязательно, например я пишу и то, и то один (не всегда, но это не важно). В таких случаях всё зависит от того как организована разработка, но чаще всего все разработчики заранее знают что именно должно быть, общаются друг с другом и договариваются как и что сделать, так что проблем в этом плане не возникает.

P.s.Ещё хочу сказать, что страницы для вывода не обязательно должны быть в файле с PHP кодом.